# spurious ajax OPTIONS request being made along with a GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am making a standard ajax request with the code below

```
let x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onload = function(event) { …};
x.open("GET", url, true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
x.send();
```

The problem is that, for some reason I can't fathom, two ajax requests are made. The first one is an OPTIONS request and the second one is the GET request that I actually wanted. Any idea why?

My server is a nodejs app which I am starting using `nodemon` which restarts the server if it senses `index.js` has changed (this is helpful in development when you don't want to stop and restart the server). With this OPTIONS business, `nodemon` thinks my `index.js` has changed and restarts `nodejs`.

Additionally, the OPTIONS request results in a successful request that returns http 200. But, nothing is returned to the web page that initiated that ajax request in the first place (this could be that immediately after the OPTIONS request, `nodejs` is restarted by `nodemon`. Then the GET request is repeated, also with 200, and the web page gets the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that, for some reason I can't fathom, two ajax requests are made. The first one is an OPTIONS request and the second one is the GET request that I actually wanted. Any idea why?

Because you're making a cross-origin call (for instance, from `http://localhost` to `http://localhost:someport`), which is normally disallowed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So the browser sends a "pre-flight" OPTIONS request to see if the server wants to allow the call via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).